# StackOverFlow и рекурсия

Tags: java, рекурсия

Пишу парсер, который получает на вход адрес сайта, а на выходе дает все ссылки на сторонние домены, которые были найдены на сайте.
Выполняет он это через рекурсивную функцию, которая парсит хтмл конкретной страницы, находит в нем линки на подстраницы (в пределах заданного сайта), записывает их в массив и вызывает сама себя для каждого линка из массива.
Так вот, для каких-то сайтов это работает нормально, но для некоторых я получаю StackOverFlow и программа крашится. Что же делать, чтобы этого избежать?

UPD1: да, я держу HashSet уже опрошенных линков.

Comment: Код-то покажите. Java по дефолту даже в неудачные фазы луны допускает больше тысячи рекурсивных вызовов. Если вам не хватает, скорее всего у вас ошибка в коде.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Перепишите на нерекурсивный вариант с использованием [`Queue<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html). Или [`Stack<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html), смотря какой порядок перебора страниц вам больше нравится.

Java знаю только издалека, но суть

```
Queue<string> queue = new Queue<string>();
queue.push(firstPageToProcess);

string pageToProcess;
while ((pageToProcess = queue.peek()) != null)
{
   // разбор страницы pageToProcess и queue.push() для новых ссылок на обработку
}
```

Comment: Хмммм, а ведь и правда. Спасибо, попробую!

Answer (score 1):

StackOverFlow это переполнение стека. Вариантов 2.

1 - слишком длинные цепочки вложений и слишком много памяти используют проверки.

2 - циклически ссылки на сайте.

2 лечится проверкой если был на странице, то не заходить.
1 лечится хорошей оптимизацией алгоритма, мощным железом и правильными опциями запуска. (java -Xms=1000m -Xmx=1000m) ну или сколько там надо.

Comment: Спасибо, да, я делаю подобную проверку, пушо каждый новый линк записывается в общий HashSet, с которым потом и сверяются остальные.

Answer (score 1):

Сделать следующие вещи:

- ограничить глубину обхода,
- держать список посещённых страниц.

Answer (score 1):

Если сайт динамический, он может содержать сколь угодно большое количество ссылок внутри себя. Например, подписывая к URL какой-нибудь `&sid=`, или к постраничной навигации какие-нибудь `&page=`, а где-нибудь на кнопочках с размером страницы `&pageSize=` (и вам придётся перебирать все возможные комбинации `page` и `pageSize`, хотя по факту это одно и то же содержимое). Плюс может быть постоянная ссылка на каждую запись, могут быть ссылки на якоря внутри страницы (типа `#blahblah`). Если вы просто собираете все ссылки в `HashSet`, вы не учтёте ни один из этих вариантов.

Answer (score 0):

Предположу, что надо указать глубину рекурсии, потому что потенциально рекурсия может быть бесконечна: страница имеет ссылку на страницу, на которой тоже есть ссылка на другую страницу и так бесконечно. Более того, есть вариант с бесконечной рекурсией, когда страницы имеют взаимные ссылки друг на друга. Без ограничения глубины, программа будет опрашивать страницы бесконечно, пока не кончится стек и не случится StackOverflow